# Inserting date multiple times from another data frame in panel data in R

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a set of panel data that I need to insert the date from another data frame.

```
allweeks <- seq(as.Date("2013-01-05"), 
            as.Date("2013-12-28"), 
            by="1 week")
```

Above is the data for the date.  Below is my data set runs from 1 to 40 observations per week.

```
mydata

    Pos  LW  WKs            Artist                  Title 
1    1  NEW   1         SAM_BAILEY             SKYSCRAPER             
2    2    4   5  PHARRELL_WILLIAMS                  HAPPY                  
3    3    3   3        LEONA_LEWIS         ONE_MORE_SLEEP         
4    4  NEW   5              AC/DC        HIGHWAY_TO_HELL        
5    5    2  13             AVICII            HEY_BROTHER            
6    6    1   6         LILY_ALLEN SOMEWHERE_ONLY_WE_KNOW 
   ...                ...                    ...
39   39 NEW   1               XYZ                    XYZ             
40   40   4   5               XYZ                    XYZ      
1    3    3   3       LEONA_LEWIS         ONE_MORE_SLEEP         
2    4  NEW   5             AC/DC        HIGHWAY_TO_HELL        
3    5    2  13            AVICII            HEY_BROTHER            
4    6    1   6        LILY_ALLEN SOMEWHERE_ONLY_WE_KNOW
```

So I want to insert each date for the above panel data from the allweeks data frame 40 times so that the result should look something like this:

```
        Pos  LW  WKs           Artist                  Title            Date
    1    1  NEW   1        SAM_BAILEY             SKYSCRAPER      2013-01-05       
    2    2    4   5 PHARRELL_WILLIAMS                  HAPPY      2013-01-05            
    3    3    3   3       LEONA_LEWIS         ONE_MORE_SLEEP      2013-01-05   
    4    4  NEW   5             AC/DC        HIGHWAY_TO_HELL      2013-01-05  
    5    5    2  13            AVICII            HEY_BROTHER      2013-01-05      
    6    6    1   6        LILY_ALLEN SOMEWHERE_ONLY_WE_KNOW      2013-01-05
       ...                ...                     ...                  ...
    39   39 NEW   1               XYZ                    XYZ      2013-01-05       
    40   40   4   5               XYZ                    XYZ      2013-01-05
    1    3    3   3       LEONA_LEWIS         ONE_MORE_SLEEP      2013-01-12   
    2    4  NEW   5             AC/DC        HIGHWAY_TO_HELL      2013-01-12  
    3    5    2  13            AVICII            HEY_BROTHER      2013-01-12      
    4    6    1   6        LILY_ALLEN SOMEWHERE_ONLY_WE_KNOW      2013-01-12
```

Any help will by greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
cbind(mydata, date=allweeks[cumsum(mydata$Pos==1)])
```

Here we just grab the next date each time `Pos=1` (assuming that indicates a new week value). -- Actually it looks like your row.names might have the numbers 1...40 but you can't have duplicate row names so I'm not sure what indicates a new week.

So if reach group really does rhave 40 entries, you could repeat each data value 40 times and cbind it

```
cbind(mydata, date=head(rep(allweeks ,each=40), nrow(mydata)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much MrFlick, this is exactly what I want!